# Using which javascript UI framework for realizing a web dashboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, yui

i'm searching for a javascript UI framework whereby it is "easy" to realize a web dashboard similar to existing platforms e.g. HootSuite or CoTweet.

I know that there are frameworks like jquery, jquery UI, YUI Library etc. .

Maybe someone has experience with such frameworks for realizing fixed dashboards (not like iGoogle).

I'm searching for opportunities to existing frameworks (Jquery UI, YUI, Knockout.js (?)).

thanks & kd

Comment: http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html

Comment: This question is entirely too subjective in its current form to answer.